# How work with string array using excel array formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array of string like this:

```
{"value 1","","Value 2","","Value 3",...}
```

I want it to be CONCATENATEd like this:

```
value 1, value 2, value 3, ...
```

**There are suggestion to use own UDF but I do not want to use any vba or UDF. I need to use native excel functions**

Like when working with number `=SUM({1,2,3,4})` will result in `10`.

I need something similar like `=CONCATENATE({"value 1","","Value 2","","Value 3",...})`

[image]

Comment: why the double quotes between comas?  was that to generate a gap?

Comment: Double quotes means string with no value. It is an empty value,

Comment: As you have seen with the answers below it is not possible to do much with formulas.  You will need to use vba.  If you have Office 365 with the latest update then you can try `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,{"value 1","","Value 2","","Value 3"})`  I am not on my machine that has Office 365 at present so I can not test it.

Comment: Just tested the formula above and it works on Office 365.  So if you have access to that you can do it with a formula otherwise you will need to migrate to Google sheets where the have something similar or rely on vba.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least on Office 2010. You would have to create your own UDF on VBA. Something like that could help you:

```
Function JoinAll(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)
'code by Jindon, MrExcel.com MVP
Dim a, i As Long
a = rng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
    If a(i, 1) = BaseValue Then JoinAll = JoinAll & _
        IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & a(i, 2)
Next
End Function
```

Comment: I know that. But I want to use native excel formula for dealing with it. Thanks again

Comment: and you did tag it as formula

Comment: I am sorry. Didn't knew it was so strict in here. Still new to the community.

Comment: Its still a valid answer, for someone looking in the future maybe, but not what the OP was going for.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reference D4, but it I revferenced the array itself then I could do the following:

```
=INDEX({"Value 1","","Value 2","","Value 3"},1)&", "&INDEX({"Value 1","","Value 2","","Value 3"},3)&", "&INDEX({"Value 1","","Value 2","","Value 3"},5)
```

The following did NOT work:

```
=INDEX(D4,1)&", "&INDEX(D4,3)&", "&INDEX(D4,5)
```

Comment: It only will work with arrays containing 3 values, but what if I have 5 or 10 value in array

Comment: then you would have to add each one in.

Comment: That is not answer I am looking for. For example We can work with numbers very easy. Like **sum({2,3,4,5})** wil result in **14**. I want something like that

Comment: @ElnurIbrahim-zade the question you asked was how to concatenate, not how to sum.  Excel is not perfect and faces many limitation.  You can do a lot more with VBA but when you restrict yourself to just formulas, you can't always achieve the same results.

Comment: another way to do it would require a helper column and as many row as you have entries in your array.